# Conversion from Decimal to octal, binary and hexadecimal in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form where a user enters a decimal number and then from the dropdown menu he chooses if he wants to convert it either to binary, octal or hexadecimal by clicking on a convert button. The new answer should be displayed in a new form saying for example: "the number in binary is....". However the code I've done doesn't seem to work. Any help would be highly appreciated. This is the code I have so far:

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <title> Convertor </title>


<style>

  .panel {
    width:400px;
    height:160px;
    background-color: #E6E6FA;
    border:2px solid blue;  
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 110%;   
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-top:15px; 
   }    

   p {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
   }

   form {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
   }

   button {
    margin-left:40px;
    margin-top:10px;
   }


   .answer {
    width:400px;
    height:90px;
    background-color: #E6E6FA;
    border:2px solid blue;  
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 110%;   
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-top:15px; 
   }    

   form {
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-top: 65px;
   }


</style>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="panel">

        <p>
            Enter decimal number to convert, select Base and click CONVERT.
        </p>

        <form>
            <input type="text">


        <select id="selectid" name="selectname">
            <option value="binary">Binary</option>
            <option value="octal">Octal</option>
            <option value="hexadecimal">Hexadecimal</option>
        </select>   

        <button id="button1" name="Button1" onclick="Answer()"> Convert 
            </button>   

            </form>


    </div>

    <div class="answer">
        <form>


        </form>

    </div>

    <script>


    function Answer() {

        if (document.getElementbyId ('selectid').value=="binary") {
            this.value=this.value.toString(2);
        }
        else if  (document.getElementbyId ('selectid').value=="octal") {
            this.value=this.value.toString(8);
        }
        else if  (document.getElementbyId ('selectid').value=="hexadecimal") {
            this.value=this.value.ToString(16);
        }
    }

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Do you know about `Number#toString`'s ability to accept a radix but just aren't using it for some reason (learning, etc.)? `(15).toString(16)` is `"f"` for instance. `(8).toString(2)` is `"1000"`.

Comment: And you did use it in your `toBin`, just apply that form to your `toOct` with `toString(8)` and so on, then it's done. However, you may need to decide where is `this.value` come from, I didn't see any code that set it.

Comment: I'm smelling homework here

Comment: Please remove the useless CSS and HTML cruft.

Answer (score 26):

Decimal to `hex`/`oct`/`bin`:

```js
const hex = (100).toString(16);     // "64"
const oct = (100).toString(8);      // "144"
const bin = (100).toString(2);      // "1100100"
```

and same backwards:

```js
const dec0 = parseInt("64", 16);     // 100
const dec1 = parseInt("144", 8);     // 100
const dec2 = parseInt("1100100", 2); // 100
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's some great code I just made to convert between binary, octal, decimal and hexadecimal:

```js
function id(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
function Convert(s, n) {
  if(parseInt(id(s).value, n)) {
    if("bin" != s) { id("bin").value = parseInt(id(s).value, n).toString(2) }
    if("oct" != s) { id("oct").value = parseInt(id(s).value, n).toString(8) }
    if("dec" != s) { id("dec").value = parseInt(id(s).value, n).toString(10) }
    if("hex" != s) { id("hex").value = parseInt(id(s).value, n).toString(16) }
  } else {
    if("bin" != s) { id("bin").value = "" }
    if("oct" != s) { id("oct").value = "" }
    if("dec" != s) { id("dec").value = "" }
    if("hex" != s) { id("hex").value = "" }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="bin" oninput="Convert('bin', 2)" placeholder="bin" spellcheck="false">
<input id="oct" oninput="Convert('oct', 8)" placeholder="oct" spellcheck="false">
<input id="dec" oninput="Convert('dec', 10)" placeholder="dec" spellcheck="false">
<input id="hex" oninput="Convert('hex', 16)" placeholder="hex" spellcheck="false">
```

Small and simple, perfect for anyone trying to find one of that kind.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a number to hexadecimal representation, you can use toString method. First argument of toString can be a radix for numbers.
Example:

```
var n = 12;
n.toString(); // "c"
```

If you want to convert back, you can use parseInt...

```
var hexnum = "c";
parseInt(hexnum,16); // 12
```

These functions works for any radix.

Here is the full source code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title> Convertor </title>
      <style>
         .panel {
           width:400px;
           height:160px;
           background-color: #E6E6FA;
           border:2px solid blue;  
           font-weight: bold;
           font-size: 110%;   
           margin-left:30px;
           margin-top:15px; 
         }    
         p {
           margin-left: 30px;
           margin-top: 15px;
         }
         form {
           margin-left: 30px;
           margin-top: 15px;
         }
         button {
           margin-left:40px;
           margin-top:10px;
         }
         .answer {
           width:400px;
           height:90px;
           background-color: #E6E6FA;
           border:2px solid blue;  
           font-weight: bold;
           font-size: 110%;   
           margin-left:30px;
           margin-top:15px; 
         }    
         form {
           margin-left: 70px;
           margin-top: 65px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="panel">
         <p>
            Enter decimal number to convert, select Base and click   CONVERT.
         </p>
         <input type="text">
         <select id="selectid" name="selectname">
            <option value="binary">Binary</option>
            <option value="octal">Octal</option>
            <option value="hexadecimal">Hexadecimal</option>
         </select>
         <button id="button1" name="Button1">Convert</button>   
      </div>
      <div class="answer" id="answer">
      </div>
      <script>
         var Answer = function(e) {
             var radix;
             var radixStr = document.getElementById('selectid').value;
             var val = parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value);
             switch(radixStr) {
               case "binary":
                 radix = 2;
                 break;
               case "octal":
                 radix = 8;
                 break;
               case "hexadecimal":
                 radix = 16;
                 break;
             } 

             document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = val.toString(radix);
             e.preventDefault();
             return false;
          }
         document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click",Answer);
         </script>
      </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. On Aptana however the program doesn't seem to work. On another editor like w3school it works. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

you can directly convert your values to binary and octal and hexadecimal like this

```
function Answer() {

    if (document.getElementbyId ('selectid').value=="binary") {
        this.value = this.value.toString(2);
    }
    else if  (document.getElementbyId ('selectid').value=="octal") {
        this.value = this.value.toString(8);
    }
    else if  (document.getElementbyId ('selectid').value=="hexadecimal") {
        this.value = this.value.toString(16);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you keep that `toHex` then?

Comment: because javascript does not have any inbuilt method to convert into hexadecimal

Comment: my bad we actually can convert to hexadecimal. i edited my answer

Comment: Thanks Taj Ahmed. I arranged the program as you told me. However now how can I implement the Convert button so that when I click it the answer is displayed in the second form

Answer (score 0):

I see some error

it's not getElementbyId ==> is getElementById,
bad use of the context(this) ... in your function Answer (this) is pointing to to the button .. I think you need to change the value on the input, right

try this:

```
function Answer(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    if (document.getElementById('selectid').value ==="binary") {
        input.value = Number(input.value).toString(2);
    }
    else if  (document.getElementById('selectid').value ==="octal") {
        input.value = Number(input.value).toString(8);
    }
    else if  (document.getElementById('selectid').value ==="hexadecimal") {
        input.value = Number(input.value).toString(16);
    }
}
```

Note: add id='input' to the input on the HTML part