# Can I use Binary or Octal in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, binary, hex, octal

I want to use Binary or Octal code like this hex code,

```
var ab=["\x61"];
document.write(ab[0]);
```

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/42693205/3521116

Answer (score 1):

You are able to use octal and binary in JavaScript (at least since ES2015) by starting numbers with 0b and 0o. For example:

```
console.log("\x61"); // hex (a)
console.log(0b11); // binary (3)
console.log(0o11); // octal (9)
```

Comment: thank you. but I want like this **var _ab=["0b11"];
document.getElementById("tex").innerHTML=[_ab[0]];**

Comment: You can do: var _ab = [0b11]; document.getElementById("tex").innerHTML=_ab[0].toString();

Comment: The toString at the end is actually not necessary so you can get rid of it if you want.